# Email sending application

Tags: c#, email, smtpclient

Can i send email without giving password on the `NetworkCredentials`? here is my code.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    MailMessage Myemail = new MailMessage();

    private void btnsendemail_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SmtpClient myGmailserver = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com",587);

        myGmailserver.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Email ID", "password");

        Myemail.From = new MailAddress("Email ID");

        Myemail.To.Add(tbTo.Text);

        Myemail.Subject = tbsubject.Text;

        Myemail.Body = tbmsg.Text;

        myGmailserver.EnableSsl = true;
        myGmailserver.Send(Myemail);
    }
}
```

on the line `myGmailserver.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("Email ID", "Password");` it asks for a password for that specific email what if i want to send email to someone and not knowing the password of that email how can i do it? please answer

Comment: "_…it asks for a password for that specific email…_" — Are you sure you read the/any documentation?

Comment: You must provide YOUR credentials, not those of the recipient.

Comment: @Crowcoder sorry i didnt get that

Comment: oh now i get it Thank you @Crowcoder :) sorry i got confused

Answer (score 0):

Ok,I got my answer the password was for the credential not for the recipients..I got another thing to ask,I add the `timer` in my form and the timer is ticking.For example at "8:00pm" an email should be sent automatically to the manager sales for sale reporting.Someone help me with this please.